# sbpl_lattice_planner on Fuerte

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, sbpl-lattice-planner, sbpl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I'm trying to compile the sbpl_lattice_planner package from the navigation_experimental Stack, i have installed all the dependencies but the compilation fails.

After checking the log of the compilation it seems that it could not found the sbpl/headers.h header file

Here is a part of the build_output.log,

> Scanning dependencies of target rosbuild_premsgsrvgen
> [  0%] Built target rosbuild_premsgsrvgen
> Scanning dependencies of target ROSBUILD_genmsg_py
> [ 40%] Built target ROSBUILD_genmsg_py
> Scanning dependencies of target ROSBUILD_genmsg_cpp
> [ 60%] Built target ROSBUILD_genmsg_cpp
> Scanning dependencies of target ROSBUILD_genmsg_lisp
> [ 80%] Built target ROSBUILD_genmsg_lisp
> Scanning dependencies of target rospack_genmsg
> [ 80%] Built target rospack_genmsg
> Scanning dependencies of target rospack_genmsg_all
> [ 80%] Built target rospack_genmsg_all
> Scanning dependencies of target rospack_genmsg_libexe
> [ 80%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
> Scanning dependencies of target rosbuild_precompile
> [ 80%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
> Scanning dependencies of target sbpl_lattice_planner
> [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sbpl_lattice_planner.dir/src/sbpl_lattice_planner.o
> In file included from /home/mario/ros_workspace/navigation_experimental/sbpl_lattice_planner/src/sbpl_lattice_planner.cpp:38:
> /home/mario/ros_workspace/navigation_experimental/sbpl_lattice_planner/include/sbpl_lattice_planner/sbpl_lattice_planner.h:16:26: error: sbpl/headers.h: No such file or directory
> In file included from /home/mario/ros_workspace/navigation_experimental/sbpl_lattice_planner/src/sbpl_lattice_planner.cpp:38:
> /home/mario/ros_workspace/navigation_experimental/sbpl_lattice_planner/include/sbpl_lattice_planner/sbpl_lattice_planner.h:69: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘SBPLPlanner’ with no type

Any ideas?

thanks a lot

Mario

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36449/sbpl_lattice_planner-on-fuerte/) by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 802 on 2012-06-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I was able to find the error, it was a matter of the include directories for the sbpl_lattice_planner. I search for the "headers.h" file using the command

> $sudo find /opt/ros/ -name "headers.h"

and get as the result:

> /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sbpl/sbpl/headers.h

so it seems that this path was not correctly established on the CMakeList.txt file, so i add it to the include directories, just adding this line to the file

> include_directories(/opt/ros/fuerte/include/sbpl)

then rebuild the package and now seems to work fine

Regards

Mario

---

Originally posted by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) with karma: 802 on 2012-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-06-25**:
was sbpl included as dependency for sbpl_lattice_planner in manifest.xml?? If yes, manual inclusion for sbpl header directory is not required!

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-06-25**:
The problem (that I also ran into) is that find_package(sbpl) returns "/opt/ros/fuerte/include/" as include path, which requires all includes to be changed from "sbpl/headers.h" into "sbpl/sbpl/headers.h".